# Jquery code issue, is there a proper format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my .js file and ever since it's been added some other Jquery features have stopped working. Is the issue in how it is written? Thanks!

```
$(window).load ->
  $('a[data-target]').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $this = $(this)
    if $this.data('target') == 'Add to'
      url = $this.data('addurl')
      new_target = "Remove from"
    else
      url = $this.data('removeurl')
      new_target = "Add to"
    $.ajax url: url, type: 'put', success: (data) ->
      $('.cart-count').html(data)
      $this.find('span').html(new_target)
      $this.data('target', new_target)

$(window).load ->
  $('#mycart .fi-x').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $this = $(this).closest('a')
    url = $this.data('targeturl')
    $.ajax url: url, type: 'put', success: (data) ->
      $('.cart-count').html(data)
      $this.closest('.cart-movie').slideUp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/), you'll likely need to convert it to javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  return $('a[data-target]').click(function(e) {
    var $this, new_target, url;
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('target') === 'Add to') {
      url = $this.data('addurl');
      new_target = "Remove from";
    } else {
      url = $this.data('removeurl');
      new_target = "Add to";
    }
    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'put',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.cart-count').html(data);
        $this.find('span').html(new_target);
        return $this.data('target', new_target);
      }
    });
  });
});

$(window).load(function() {
  return $('#mycart .fi-x').click(function(e) {
    var $this, url;
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this).closest('a');
    url = $this.data('targeturl');
    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'put',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.cart-count').html(data);
        return $this.closest('.cart-movie').slideUp();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow, I knew the code I had was a bit off from the regular javascript I'm used to. I didn't know the format was so important when integrating it amongst other functions. I can't thank you enough for doing this! I know very little about javascript & other scripting languages, couldn't have done it without your help @Stuart.

Comment: It's a pleasure Jake, have fun with it!